# Concise introduction to Beta transformations

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm looking for a concise introductory on the subject of beta transformations on the circle. I've found things that are related to its applications in the computational field or in number theory. A good intro for me will include basic definitions, main results about the transformations themselves and references.

**Basic Notion:** If $X=[0,1]$, then for all $\beta >0$ the associated $\beta$ transformation is $T_{\beta} x = \beta x \, {\rm mod} (1)$, where $x\in X$. This can be easily embeded in the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ by $T_{\beta} e^{2\pi i x} = e^{2\pi i \beta x} $.

The above formulation is not exact, as was implied in the comments. Probably this is why I'm in need of a tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Is it well defined on the circle? If I replace $x$ by $x+k$ for an integer $k$, I should have the same left hand side. But if $\beta$ is not an integer, I seem to have a different right hand side.

Comment: @BenMcKay from the references given, I see your point. However, I don't think I'm yet in the position to give the right formulation in the OP.

Answer (score 7):

Everything I know about beta-transformations I learned from Charlene Kalle, whose PhD thesis (Utrecht University, 2009) can be downloaded here: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~kallecccj/proefschrift.pdf. It is interesting, well written and even funny at times, but of course being a thesis it focuses on proving new results rather than providing an introduction to the subject. However, the first chapter might be a good place to start. It does include basic definitions and main results about the transformations and the thesis as a whole includes a lot of references.

Another book that might fit the bill is reference [DK02a] in the thesis:

K. Dajani and C. Kraaikamp. Ergodic theory of numbers, volume 29 of Carus
Mathematical Monographs. Mathematical Association of America, Washington,
DC, 2002.

Comment: I think a better place to start is where the notion is firstly proposed, say Renyi's paper.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are several papers that can give you a good introduction. The seminal papers of Parry and Rényi have been already mentioned as well as Dajani-Kraikaamp's book. I think that Nikita Sidorov's paper [Arithmethic Dynamics](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nikita/ad.pdf) is very useful as well as his [lecture notes](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~nikita/qmul-2010.pdf). Also Dajani&Kraaikamp's paper [From Greedy to Lazy expansions and their driving dynamics](http://dutiosc.twi.tudelft.nl/~cork/monthly.pdf) is relevant as well as Komornik's paper [Expansions in noninteger bases](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?agg_year_2011=2011&batch_title=Selected%20Matches%20for%3A%20Items%20authored%20by%20Komornik%2C%20Vilmos&fmt=doc&pg1=INDI&s1=104490&searchin=&sort=newest&vfpref=html&r=1&mx-pid=3054428).

Now, [Simon Baker's](https://simonbakermaths.wordpress.com/) and [Derong Kong's](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Derong_Kong) papers contain very well written brief introductions to the topic.

**EDIT**  I found these notes today. 
http://wisdyn.math.uni-bremen.de/betabremen.pdf
http://wisdyn.math.uni-bremen.de/Lingmin.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The reference pointed out by Vincent are both thesis, I think a more appropriate introductory level material is [Brown&Yin](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0143385700000699). And it is the only modern paper that I touched tangential to beta expansion.

> [Brown&Yin]Brown, Gavin, and Qinghe Yin. "$\ beta $-transformation,
>   natural extension and invariant measure." Ergodic Theory and Dynamical
>   Systems 20.05 (2000): 1271-1285.

Another source is Renyi's original paper where $\beta$-transformation is first invented.

> Rényi, Alfréd. "Representations for real numbers and their ergodic
>   properties." Acta Mathematica Hungarica 8.3-4 (1957): 477-493.

and a follow-up paper,

> Parry, William. "On the β-expansions of real numbers." Acta
>   Mathematica Hungarica 11.3-4 (1960): 401-416.

Comment: And a quick search gives the following paper which may be of some relevance, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2257842_The_Natural_Extension_of_the_Beta-Transformation